# Taking screenshots in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a project where screenshot is being taken when user visits one of the pages, and I was wondering why is screenshot result from ***useEffect*** hook sometimes null and the function inside this hook is executed few times.
Here is the code in react:

```
function Products() {

const ref = createRef(null);
const [screenShoot, takeScreenShot] = useScreenshot();
const getImage = () => takeScreenShot(ref.current);


const addScreenShoot = () => {
    getImage();
    let data = {
        id: jwtDecode(AuthService.getCurrentUser().accessToken).id,
        screenShoot
    };

    axios.post("http://localhost:8080/api/auth/screenshoot", data).then((response) => {
        console.log(response.data);
    });
}
useEffect(() => {
    addScreenShoot();
}, []);

return (
    <div ref={ref}>
        Welcome user
    </div>
)
```

I am fairly new to React so I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: have you used the correct dependency array in the `useEffect`? that we can't see in this code? if there is no dependency array, it will run the `useEffect` on every render.

Comment: I accidently forgot to add useEffect to the question code. Now you can see it I hope.

Comment: in functional components, you should use the useRef hook not createRef e.g: const ref = useRef(null)

Comment: Okey, I will do that thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [takeScreenShot](https://github.com/vre2h/use-react-screenshot/blob/master/src/index.js), it returns a Promise function.

```
useEffect(() => {
    getImage().then((val) => {
      console.log(val);
      // other codes are here
    });
  }, []);
```